# Open Source webapp that shows PC / Projector status in 30+ Lecture rooms

Tags: web-applications, utility

I am looking for a simple web application that only has a simple graphical representation of the current status of 30+ lecture rooms. I.e. Green = good, Red=bad i.e. PC or Projector not working. With a little message and a ETA as well.

I am not looking for monitoring software, merely a way for a tech to flag a room as "technically challenged" until 1PM or until "Friday 10AM". With a message for those lecturers who are interested: "Waiting on replacement bulb" or "Power supply gone"

I know this is a simple thing to code up yourself, but I am looking for something that has been around for a few years that has some cool extra little functionality that you wouldn't think of yourself. I just can't find anything like that out there.

And just to be clear: 
**not** monitoring software, more like **lecturer feedback** web app.

Also: Not **room bookings** or **timetabling**. These would actually be a drawback for what I have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do you get the status? Specifically of the projectors?

My honest recommendation would be - since it would probably be useful for your techs as well - to setup a minimal Nagios install to monitor everything of interest, and then code up a simple PHP page to display the current status and comments/acknowledgment messages as you want.

I've never seen anything like this, probably because the "cool extra little functionality" that most people want is automated monitoring.

My advice:

1. use Nagios and code a custom front-end
2. if you have a ticketing system, write something up that pulls from that
3. code up something yourself in 20 minutes, add features as needed.

Comment: The status is going to come from the Lecturers and the AV guy who cleans the filters and changes the bulbs. It is not monitoring I am looking for, it is so that a lecturer can glance at a page in the morning to see if all the lecture PCs and projectors are **green** or else try to change rooms. I.e. if a projector is in for repair for two days, that would be **red** with an ETA of April 29th for repair.

Comment: I think I will do the code it up myself, it's just that it will take me much longer than 20 minutes! Maybe I should mess around with it for a year or two and "Open Source" it to get someone to fix it for me! I'll accept your answer if no one knows of such an app.

Comment: If you're going to be doing PHP, feel free to email me (address listed at http://blog.jasonantman.com) if you hit any walls.

Comment: Gotta award the rep for this! Thanks, I should be able to put something small together myself though. It will just be done in my _spare_ time!